# iTunes resizing photos on sync

Tags: iphone, sync, photos

When I synch my photos into iPhone/iPod through iTunes the photos are being resized to smaller ones. I need to get high resolution images without being resized into the device. Is there any way to do this other than saving images from mail or from browser etc ?.

Answer (score 2):

In setting of synchonisation you can check option which says "Include full resolution photos". One con could be, that you have to have your device in Disk use mode. So if you don't it could be time expensive for you, becouse of the again uploading the content to the device

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1678 - paragraph 5

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also browse to your phone from your computer just like a digital camera and copy the files directly into photos directory.